# Create a canvas-like style (a blurred effect)

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, sharpness, blur

Hi I would like to have a fluffy effect for the details of my image, and I have tried tools such as Sharpen, Blur in Fliter, and Clarity in RAW manipulation, but in vain.

The left hand side is the original pic and the right one is what I want.
 [image]

[image]

[image]

The original pic ： https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alipxzqy9-AoazjWAKXR3PD_hwU

The ideal pic: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alipxzqy9-AobA5mrRvlzz_6bXM

Comment: I have to admit, *not* what I immediately pictured when you said a “fluffy, furry effect.”

Comment: @Hueco Well... Sorry for the vague description, maybe blurred is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you seek is one of the following:

- Soft focus.
- Glow.  Don't know the proper name for the appearance, but many older lenses give everything a "glow" or "halo" when shot wide open.
- [Orton effect.](https://www.capturelandscapes.com/orton-effect-explained/)  Apparently used in a lot of landscape photos.  Originated in dark room, but digitally mimicked by combining blurred and sharp layers.